# function returns [object Object] javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash, hashtable

I have this subpart of my code:

```
var t = {
   "a" : "coucou",
   "b" : "salut",
   "c" : [1, 2, 3],
   "sous" : {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "spam" : [ 1,2, {"egg" : "42"}]}
   };

   for ( k in t) {
    console.log(k + ’ : ’ + t[k]) ;
   }
```

I don't really understand why the result of the "spam" key is [object Object].

```
a : coucou
b : salut
c : 1,2,3
sous : [object Object]
```

Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: because `sous` is an object

Comment: You are concatenating string and object. Use `,` to console 2 variables  like `console.log(k,  t[k]);`

Answer (score 2):

Use comma(,) in `console.log` instead of concatenation operator `+`:

```js
var t = {
   "a" : "coucou",
   "b" : "salut",
   "c" : [1, 2, 3],
   "sous" : {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "spam" : [ 1,2, {"egg" : "42"}]}
   };

for ( k in t) {
 console.log(k + ' : ' , t[k]) ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! 
If I use comma(,) what will be the output of the spam,?

Comment: @Jamin it's in the code snippet above

Answer (score 1):

When you write the expression `k + ’ : ’ + t[k]`, the `+` operator will work as a concatenation operator. It will force the operand on the right hand side to be converted to a string. For objects, this means calling their `.toString()` method, which by default simply returns `[object Object]`.

More info here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString